# Removed from sudoers file without any other users on the server

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

Today i logged into my server (which only has internal access and single user, me) to the message "iarp not in sudoers file ....". My old byobu session was still running to i connected to that and i can sudo all i want in here without errors, but now i'm worried if i close this session i will lose all sudo abilities.

Ever heard of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you create a "backdoor" account ("toor" is one popular name for these types of accounts) and grant it access to "sudo" and pretty much everything that root normally has access to.  Then, test it to make sure it works before assuming that it will.

More importantly, you may also wish to make a backup of important key files on your system (data, system configuration/security, etc.) before doing anything else.  Of course, if things go really wrong you should be able to connect the hard drive as a secondary to another Linux/Unix box and mount it (which should at least make it possible to access your data).